# jquery less/more text dynamic content

Tags: jquery, mustache, truncate

I've got this `mustache` template:

```
<script id="stemplate" type="text/template">
    {{#data}}
        <li class="service-listitem">
            <div class="lstHeading"><b>{{Type}}:</b> {{Name}}</div>
            <div class="service-item">
                <div class="infoCap">
                    {{Information}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    {{/data}}
</script>
```

which is used for infinite scroll.

But `Information` has a max length of 500 chars, and I want to limit it with 100/150 with a text truncator. I found [jTruncate](http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=jTruncate) and tried to use it like this:

```
$('.infoCap').jTruncate({
    length: 100,
    minTrail: 0,
    moreText: "[see all]",
    lessText: "[hide extra]",
    ellipsisText: " (truncated)",
    moreAni: "fast",
    lessAni: 2000
});
```

But this doesn't work for dynamically added content. I should be using `on()`, but there is no event that I know of that jTruncate supports for this purpose.

So I'm kind of stuck here. Any one knows how to accomplish this? Doesn't necessarily have to be jTruncate.

Comment: May not help your problem, but you can also take a look at dotdotdot.js (http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) for text truncating.  I have used it a few times at my job, and it gets the job done nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding `$('.infoCap').expander();` in the `success` function of an AJAX call.

Note that `expander()` is from another plug in that does the same thing as JTruncate, but has some more options.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds somewhat related to [Mustache doesn't handle events properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216400/mustache-doesnt-handle-events-properly).  Might just need that callback option so your template has time to render.

Answer (score 0):

First time i see this kind of problem. Maybe a trick would be to assign the value attribute to the element right before '.service-listitem'.

Every time you dynamically add content then you will also randomly change the value attribute with another value. By this way i think you create a potential 'change' event.

If that works then it is easy to to something like this:

```
$('.element_with_value').on('change', function(){

    $('.infoCap').jTruncate({

        length: 100,
        minTrail: 0,
        moreText: "[see all]",
        lessText: "[hide extra]",
        ellipsisText: " (truncated)",
        moreAni: "fast",
        lessAni: 2000

    });

});
```

First time i face this problem so this is a potential solution.

Comment: It's a `li` item which will be appended to a `ul`. For example, if I scroll down, i'll get (for example) 5 new records. And this template will be applied 5 times. Than the `li`'s wont be changed after that. So I don't think `change` event can be applied in this situation. Thought I have tried your approach, but to no avail.